# Remove duplicates in org.dom4j.Document object

Tags: java, xml, dom, duplicates, dom4j

Is it somehow possible to filter all duplicate elements on the same level in an `org.dom4j.Document` object in Java?

For example

```
<parent>
    <child><value>1</value></child>
    <child><value>1</value></child>
    <child><value>3</value></child>
</parent>
```

should lead to

```
<parent>
    <child><value>1</value></child>
    <child><value>3</value></child>
</parent>
```

Is there already a built in functionality for this? Or maybe a library that one could use?

Comment: Have you looked at Node.selectElements method? There is an optional removeDuplicates flag. Maybe this will help: http://akmishra30.blogspot.co.at/2014/01/dom4j-remove-duplicate-xml-elements.html

But if you want to directly manipulate the structure of the document and not to work with lists, I'm afraid you might have to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No functionality for this.

The org.w3c.dom.Node interface provides the removeChild method
Code example

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0];

xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(y)
```

Or use XSLT

```
- Documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14252/adx_j_xslt.htm
- Example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10914512/4017037
```