# SimpleXML - how to ignore duplicate tags in bad XML?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I am using java SimpleXML to parse XML from a number of applications.

Many applications create quirky XML implementations of this supposed 'standard', such as putting in an 'enabled' tag more than once.

In this situation, I just want to ignore the second one as it is a mistake and has same value as first anyway, but SimpleXML throws an exception "Element 'enabled' is already used"

How do I prevent this?

This is the field that is complained about.

```
@Element(required = false)
protected boolean enabled = true;
```

The XML is huge so don't want to post it. Is there a way to get SimpleXML to report the line number that the caused the error?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Updated to show the java field annotaion, but massive XML, so would rather track down the exact line number to post a snippet. Is there a way to get the line number?

Comment: I have another issue too. Even though I am using Root(strict = false) and read(strict=false), simplexml is still being strict. I really want it to ignore problems.

Comment: Cant u use XSLT first to preprocess the XML to remove duplicated tag and than use SimpleXML to parse it...for removing duplicate elements using XSLT you could follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912544/removing-duplicate-elements-with-xslt

Comment: I will try that next but would prefer first to get SimpleXML to stop being strict with validation. I can't seem to turn it off but unsure why. I would hope that in non strict mode it might simply ignore the second setting of that property. Any ideas why it may ignoring my attempt to turn off strict?

Answer (score 1):

try to following annotations:

```java
   class RepeatElements {
      @ElementListUnion({
         @ElementList(entry = "enable", 
           type = Boolean.class, inline = true)
        })
      private ArrayList<Boolean> enables = new ArrayList<>();

      public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO check size
        return enables.get(0).booleanValue();
      }
    }
```

ouput for class RepeatElements with some "enables"

```xml
    <repeatElements>
        <enable>true</enable>
        <enable>true</enable>
        <enable>true</enable>
    </repeatElements>
```

Comment: Thanks that would work. I was thinking of doing this as a last resort. But I am still totally confused about why I cannot turn off strict validation. Any ideas about that?

Comment: I think if you annotate the class attribute `enabled` with `@Element(required=false)`, simple-framework expects exact one or zero xml elements named "enabled", with `strict=false` simple-framework skips elements with other names than "enabled", two ore more elements with name "enabled" is an error and could not be skipped

Comment: here you find a gist https://gist.github.com/momolinus/5104fa890936d0cd58dd with the sample