# How XSL will work If we have more then one same record in XML, ignore them and extract only rest data

Tags: xml, xslt

How XSL will work If we have more then one same record in XML, ignore them and extract only rest data. my xsl code handling only duplicate value, i need only that record which is not duplicate or more then one. Below is my XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:for-each-group select="creation" group-by="id">
<xsl:sequence select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<creations>
<creation>
<id>074</id>
</creation>
<creation>
<id>074</id>
</creation>
<creation>
<id>001</id>
</creation>
<creation>
<id>074</id>
</creation>
</creations>
```

Expected output:

```
  <creation>
  <id>001</id>
  </creation>
```

Comment: You've been here a year, asked 9 questions, received downvotes on some and upvotes on 0, and accepted 0 answers.  ***You really must read and embrace [ask]  and other [help] topics in order to use this site effectively.***  Otherwise, you're just wasting everyone's time, including your own.

Comment: See [Remove duplicated elements via XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912544/removing-duplicate-elements-with-xslt)

Comment: I have tried with this code, but that not working:                     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="ccid" match="creations" use="id"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="creation[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('ccid', creations)[1]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do to get the expected result is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="creation-by-id" match="creation" use="id"/> 

<xsl:template match="/creations">
    <xsl:copy-of select="creation[count(key('creation-by-id', id)) = 1]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note however that if there are two or more unique `creation` nodes, the result will not be well-formed XML (no single root element).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with Muenchian-Grouping:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="ccid" match="creation" use="id"/>

    <xsl:template match="creations">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="creation[count(key('ccid', id)) &gt; 1]"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0 with grouping**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="creations">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="creation" group-by="id" >
            <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) eq 1">
                <xsl:sequence select="."></xsl:sequence>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*Remove all duplicates of `creation/id`, so only unique `creation/id` remain.*