# XSLT how to compare elements using xsl:if for below scenario

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

sample XML code below as input, here we have 3 "tpi" nodes inside "ncj" node. i have a "xsl:for-each select="n1:tpi"" , before "xsl:for-each select="n1:tpi"" i need a "xsl:if", where this if condition should not allow duplicates of child, where in the below sample the first and third "tpi" nodes are same inside, so "xsl:if" should allow only first "tpi" node not the third "tpi" node. can anyone suggest a "xsl:if" condition for this scenario?

```
<ncj>
    <tpi>
        <ta>01</ta>
        <t>
            <cde>1234</cde>
            <tt>
                <a>sample1</a>
                <b>sample2</b>
            </tt>
        </t>
    </tpi>
    <tpi>
        <ta>02</ta>
        <t>
            <cde>654</cde>
            <tt>
                <a>sample2</a>
                <b>sample1</b>
            </tt>
        </t>
    </tpi>
    <tpi>
        <ta>01</ta>
        <t>
            <cde>1234</cde>
            <tt>
                <a>sample1</a>
                <b>sample2</b>
            </tt>
        </t>
    </tpi>
</ncj>
```

Comment: why an `xsl-if`? any reason for not using `preceding-sibling` to filter duplicates?

Comment: i am very new @derloopkat, so you could suggest me any ways! just i need to pass only non duplicate data into that "xsl:for-each"
```
<any filter methods>
<xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</filter method end>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicate elements with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912544/removing-duplicate-elements-with-xslt)

Comment: but that has only single node, where i have data in multiple nodes and all data should be compared in my scenario @derloopkat

Comment: @vetha If you need to compare multiple nodes then make your key a concatenation of multiple node values.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, i am a newbie to this platform so i don't know how the syntax would be, so could any of you can give a exact code for my scenario would be appreciated! thanks in advance and explanations for the same code would be much appreciated, since learning is better than hearing

Comment: Try `<xsl:key name="k1" match="tpi" use="concat(ta, '|', t/cde,  '|', tt/a,  '|', tt/b)"/>`. Also read http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html. If you can't make it work, post your code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the key is fine and i have read the muenchian.html which you shared here! thanks for the info, but still how to write the select function using this key? in a xsl:for-each since my code lines are nearly 12000+ thats why i am hesitating to upload it here

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: OK you can check out my minimal xml file in the url https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivJsb/5 and the required output is commented in the same url below the xml file @michael.hor257k . in that we need to remove the duplicates and other than duplicates should be written with sequential numbers