# Eliminating duplicates from xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, soa

I'm New to xslt can any one help me on this

I tried several ways but no luck can you please help.

I can only use XSLT 1.0

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OrderNumberVar>
       <VariableCollection xmlns="http://www.mcp.com/xsd" 
       xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" 
       xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MCB_SOA/JDE" 
   xmlns:tns="http://www.mcb.com/xsd">
      <tns:Variable>
         <tns:OrderNumber>156708</tns:OrderNumber>
      </tns:Variable>
      <tns:Variable>
         <tns:OrderNumber>156708</tns:OrderNumber>
      </tns:Variable>
      <tns:Variable>
         <tns:OrderNumber>263932</tns:OrderNumber>
      </tns:Variable>
   </VariableCollection>
```

Need to eliminate the duplicates from the above xml

```
</VariableCollection>
      <tns:Variable>
         <tns:OrderNumber>156708</tns:OrderNumber>
      </tns:Variable>
      <tns:Variable>
         <tns:OrderNumber>263932</tns:OrderNumber>
      </tns:Variable>
</VariableCollection>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344458/removing-duplicates-in-xsl)

Comment: Start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 you can do like this, checking with `preceding-sibling` values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns="http://www.mcp.com/xsd"
    xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MCB_SOA/JDE"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.mcb.com/xsd"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs plnk wsdl client tns xsl" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:Variable">
        <xsl:variable name="current">
            <xsl:value-of select="tns:OrderNumber"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::tns:Variable[tns:OrderNumber=$current])">
            <tns:Variable>
                <tns:OrderNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$current"/>
                </tns:OrderNumber>
            </tns:Variable>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not a good method - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: You can add a name to the copying template, and then call that template inside of your if test.

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.mcp.com/xsd"
    xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MCB_SOA/JDE" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.mcb.com/xsd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="VariableCollection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tns:Variable" group-by="tns:OrderNumber">
                <tns:Variable>
                    <tns:OrderNumber><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></tns:OrderNumber>
                    </tns:Variable>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
use it.
```

Comment: OP ask for XSLT 1.0

Comment: I can only use xslt 1.0

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.mcp.com/xsd"
    xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MCB_SOA/JDE" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.mcb.com/xsd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="uniq" match="tns:Variable" use="tns:OrderNumber"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="VariableCollection">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="tns:Variable[ generate-id() = generate-id(key('uniq',tns:OrderNumber)[1])]">
                <tns:Variable><tns:OrderNumber><xsl:value-of select="key('uniq',tns:OrderNumber)[1]"/></tns:OrderNumber></tns:Variable>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
You can also do using xsl:key
```

Comment: Are you sure? (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mj/1) Maybe you meant something like this instead? (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mj/2)

Comment: Sorry sir i forgot to change (xpath-default-namespace) default namespace as it is not allow in xslt 1.0